# Почему не работает регулярное выражение поиска номера телефона в строке?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно выделить номер из строки.

Есть два приемлемых варианта:

```
+7911111111
8911111111
```

Иногда приходит что-то вроде 8-911-111-11-11, которое недопустимо.

Я написал

```php
preg_replace("/[0-9\\+][0-9]{10}/", '', $phone);
```

Я думал, что первый символ либо число, либо плюс, а остальные — числа,
и тогда мне будут приходить валидные номера.

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $phone)` - не оно? [Поиграться](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08392830d7593c6d2eceddfe004e3676c1abd158)

Comment: @XelaNimed Начальный плюс удалять - нехорошо. Это позволит ввести невалидный номер `7911111111`. Надо сохранять все плюсы, а потом сверять с двумя указанными шаблонами.

Comment: Почему бы не добавлять по-умолчанию плюс к номеру, а пользователю разрешить вводить только цифры?! Плюс - это по сути сокращённые два нуля `00` в номере телефона.

Comment: @XelaNimed первая регулярка не подходит. Могу потерять +. Есть вариант конечно брать только последние 10 символов. И дописывать +7 . Но в таком случае нужно будет проверять если что-то в переменной вообще, потому что если нет, то у меня появятся поля где только +7. Поэтому хотелось бы регулярокй ограничиться

Comment: `preg_match_all('~(?<!\w)(?:\+7|8)\d{9}(?!\d)~', $text, $matches)`? https://regex101.com/r/COn6kD/1

Comment: Постарайтесь описать как можно подробней все детали относящиеся к Вашему вопросу, т.к. номер может быть в международном формате, в формате определённой страны, в формате определённого города, `800е` номера тоже могут быть, + сотовые...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew d{10} наверное нужно? И это выражение не нашло +7911-111-11-11 хотя номера такого типа мне и нужно преобразовать в +79111111111

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 11 в номере

Comment: `(?<!\d|\d-)(?:\+7|8)(?:-?\d){10}(?!-?\d)`?  https://regex101.com/r/COn6kD/2. Или `(?<!\d|\d-)(?:\+7|8)(?:-?\d){9,10}(?!-?\d)`? https://regex101.com/r/COn6kD/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew во второй вариант находит) Спасибо. А как теперь убрать тире в номере? Или пробелы лишние. Чтобы было либо +79111111111 или 89111111111

Comment: Используйте `str_replace` / `preg_replace`. Например, ``str_replace('-', '', $result)``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как правильный, если он помог вам решить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```php
preg_match_all('~(?<!\d|\d-)(?:\+7|8)(?:-?\d){9,10}(?!-?\d)~', $text, $matches)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/COn6kD/3).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\d|\d-)` - отрицающий блок предварительного просмотра назад, который отменяет совпадение, сразу перед которым есть цифра или цифра + дефис
- `(?:\+7|8)` - плюс + `7` или `8`
- `(?:-?\d){9,10}` - 9 или 10 повторов необязательного дефиса и одной цифры
- `(?!-?\d)` - отрицающий блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, сразу после которого есть цифра или дефис + цифра.

После того, как вы найдёте все совпадения, вы сможете удалить дефисы с помощью `str_replace('-', '', $matches[0])`.

См. [пример работы кода](https://3v4l.org/crfDl):

```php
$text = 'Есть два приемлих варианта +7911111111 и 8911111111. Просто иногда приходит что-то типа такого 8-911-111-11-11 что не есть гуд';
if (preg_match_all('~(?<!\d|\d-)(?:\+7|8)(?:-?\d){9,10}(?!-?\d)~', $text, $matches)) {
    $results = str_replace('-', '', $matches[0]);
    print_r($results);
}
// => Array ( [0] => +7911111111 [1] => 8911111111 [2] => 89111111111 )
```